# Why won't R recognize numbers 10 or above in my data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm still fairly new to R, so maybe this is an obvious fix, but I'm having trouble with R recognizing numbers above 9; as shown below, I'm [trying to order the data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WafL6.png) userCommentsDF and eventually remove any numComments entries of 10 or higher. When I order the data frame, everything is in order as it should be, except for entries of ten or higher, [which appear together seemingly randomly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Tn3T.png) in the middle of the dataset (between entries of 1 and 2). In addition, when I check using summary(), R tells me that there aren't any observations within that column above 9.

Here is the code I'm currently working on:

```
positions <- order(userCommentDF$numComments, decreasing = T)
orderedUserComments <- userCommentDF[positions, ]
summary(userCommentDF$numComments > 9)
```

Here is the code I used to create the data frame:

```
userCommentDF <- data.frame("test", "data", "age", "gender", "location", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(userCommentDF) <- c("user", "numComments", "age", "gender", "location")
userNumber <- 1
for (user in commenters){
        userCount <- (count(comments, comAuthor == user)[2, 2])
        aDF <- data.frame(user, userCount, comAge[userNumber], comGender[userNumber], comAuthorLocation[userNumber])
        names(aDF) <- c("user", "numComments", "age", "gender", "location")
        userCommentDF <- rbind(userCommentDF, aDF)
        userNumber <- userNumber + 1
}
userCommentDF <- userCommentDF[-c(1), ]
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening or how I might fix it?

Thank you!

EDIT: I used as.numeric() which worked.

Comment: IN the example, what is `commenters`

Comment: I can't reproduce `commenter` from your example. But its probably because the variable is a character variable instead of numeric.  Use `str(data.frame)` to see how it is currently coded.  You can convert to numeric by `as.numeric()`.  You can convert from a factor to numeric as `as.numeric(as.character())`

Comment: @akaDrHouse you're right, it's a character variable and that's why it was acting up. Is there a way I can permanently change it to a numeric variable so I don't have to use as.numeric() each time? Thanks for your help!